# How can i solve Fill datatable from linq query error?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm write this query:

```
IEnumerable<TAXBILLCRMTEMP> query_detail_allrow = from c in mainbehzad.TAXBILLCRMTEMPs.AsEnumerable()
                                        select c;
```

and this line:

```
DataTable dt = query_detail_allrow.CopyToDataTable<TAXBILLCRMTEMP>();
```

but i get this error from up line:

> The type 'REPORT_MANAGER.TAXBILLCRMTEMP' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'REPORT_MANAGER.TAXBILLCRMTEMP' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. D:\MASHHAD
>   SOFWARE\ver2\REPORT MANAGER\REPORT
>   MANAGER\TaxCRMBILLLOAD.cs 227 28  REPORT MANAGER

what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: how can I reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you return data to assign AsEnumerable like this

```
IEnumerable<TAXBILLCRMTEMP> query_detail_allrow = (from c in mainbehzad.TAXBILLCRMTEMP
                                        select c).AsEnumerable();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<TAXBILLCRMTEMP> query_detail_allrow = mainbehzad.TAXBILLCRMTEMP.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: How would that solve the problem? Did you read the included compiler error?